# ¿Como poder eliminar nodos de listas doblemente enlazadas de entero mediante un rango establecido por el usuario? (con libreria list)

Tags: c++, lista

El ejercicio trata de crear una lista enlazada doble o circulas en el cual se deben eliminar nodos que esten fuera de un rango de valores leidos desde el teclado,
la lista la deje global para hacer mas facil su uso en una funcion donde se implemeta lo que piden, el codigo queda de esta manera:

```
void ajustarLista(int iz, int der){
    int x = 0;
    for(auto iter = ListadeNum.begin(); iter != ListadeNum.end(); ++iter){
        x = iter->dato;
        if(x <= iz){
            iter = ListadeNum.erase(iter);
        }
        if(x >= der){
            iter = ListadeNum.erase(iter);
        }
    }
}
```

Pero el problema es que no borra los datos que debe borrar y al leer de nuevo la lista saca datos que no son correctos acorde al rango.
Aqui esta todo el codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct nodo{
    int dato;
};
nodo numero;
list<nodo> ListadeNum;

void ajustarLista(int a, int b);

int main(){
    
    cout << "\nPrograma de una lista doblemente enlazada de 50 numeros al azar\n\n";
    int num=0, c;
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "[ ";

    for(c=1; c<=50; c++){
        num = 1 + rand() % (1000 -1);
        numero.dato = num;
        cout << num << " ";
        ListadeNum.insert(ListadeNum.end(), numero);
    }
    cout << "]\n";

    int exIzq = 0, exDer = 0;
    cout << "Seleccione el rango en que debe estar la lista: \n";
    cout << "Extremo izquierdo: "; cin >> exIzq;
    cout << "Extremo derecho: "; cin >> exDer;
    ajustarLista(exIzq, exDer); // Se llama a la funcion

    for(nodo i: ListadeNum){

        cout << i.dato <<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void ajustarLista(int iz, int der){
    int x = 0;
    for(auto iter = ListadeNum.begin(); iter != ListadeNum.end(); ++iter){
        x = iter->dato;
        if(x <= iz){
            iter = ListadeNum.erase(iter);
        }
        if(x >= der){
            iter = ListadeNum.erase(iter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir los datos con que estás probando el programa? ¿Cuál es la entrada que ofreces y la salida que esperas?

Comment: Hola, claro los datos con lo que lleno la lista son solamente enteros, probe una funcion rand() para que los genere un rango de 1 y 50
`
int num=0, c;
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "[ ";
    for(c=1; c<=50; c++){
        num = 1 + rand() % (1000 -1);
        numero.dato = num;
`

Comment: No te pregunté qué tipo de datos guardas, te pregunté los datos que guardas y qué datos introduces y qué datos te devuelve y qué datos esperabas recibir.

Answer (score 2):

Estás usando iteradores para recorrer la lista y eliminar elementos:

```
void ajustarLista(int iz, int der){
    int x = 0;
    for(auto iter = ListadeNum.begin(); iter != ListadeNum.end(); ++iter){
        x = iter->dato;
        if(x <= iz){
            iter = ListadeNum.erase(iter);
        }
        if(x >= der){
            iter = ListadeNum.erase(iter);
        }
    }
}
```

Y como bien has notado, el método `erase` te devuelve un iterador. El motivo es que al eliminar `iter` de la lista, ya no puedes usar dicho iterador porque ha dejado de pertenecer a la lista. Para solucionar ese inconveniente, el método `erase` te devuelve un iterador que apunta al **siguiente elemento de la lista**.

es decir, si tu tienes una lista tal que

```
A <-> B <-> C <-> D <-> E
      ^
      iter
```

y hacemos `iter = lista.erase(iter)` nos queda lo siguiente:

```
A <-> C <-> D <-> E
      ^
      iter
```

Da la casualidad que la llamada a `erase` se encuentra dentro de un bucle `for` que, en cada iteración, incrementa `iter`, por lo que en nuestro ejemplo acabaríamos con:

```
A <-> C <-> D <-> E
            ^
            iter
```

Es decir, hemos dejado el nodo C sin comprobar.

Y ahí está el problema. Has programado un incremento incondicional del iterador cuando la realidad es que dicho incremento solo debe realizarse cuando no has borrado un elemento de la lista:

```
void ajustarLista(int iz, int der){
    int x = 0;
    for(auto iter = ListadeNum.begin(); iter != ListadeNum.end(); /* ++iter */){
        x = iter->dato;
        if(x <= iz){
            iter = ListadeNum.erase(iter);
        }
        else if(x >= der){
            iter = ListadeNum.erase(iter);
        }
        else
        {
            ++iter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya veo, ¡muchas gracias en serio! Me has salvado de una.
Feliz día